# Unable to click an element using XPATH(Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to Click an element using the Selenium

```
URL = 'https://www.portlandoregon.gov/police/71978'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriver_Path, options = options)
driver.get(URL)
  
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dijit_layout_LayoutContainer_0"]/div/div[2]/div/div'))).click()
```

I tried to click "Download Open Data" but it gave me Timeout exception as it did not find the specified element.
Please help me on this

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Pavan $uvarna\Auto_Update.py", line 90, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dijit_layout_LayoutContainer_0"]/div/div[2]'))).click()
  File "C:\Users\Pavan K\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the click action to `DownloadOpenData` variable and there is no need to do that. Try just clicking instead:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dijit_layout_LayoutContainer_0"]/div/div[2]/div/div'))).click()
```

Also, you might wait for the element to be clickable instead of only visible before actually attempting a click.

Comment: Hi, I tried after removing the variable still I see the same error.

Comment: Please expand the post, the message is still missing.